# I can't change the div text with Jquery append

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

My plan is I want to change image with Jquery. I have other image named `choose 01.png`, `choose 02.png` and so on. I want the image is changed from `number 01.png` to `choose 01.png` when its clicked. And if 5 image is clicked and changed, I want to remove them from the table and changing what's inside the `order` id with new `<p>`. Changing image is just for marking.

This is my attempt to change it with jquery but apparently it doesn't work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Magic</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="magic.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="board">
        <div id="orders"></div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><img id="00" class="card" src="images/number 00.png"  alt="0"></td>
                <td><img id="01" class="card" src="images/number 01.png" alt="1"></td>
                <td><img id="02" class="card" src="images/number 02.png" alt="2"></td>
                <td><img id="03" class="card" src="images/number 03.png" alt="3"></td>
                <td><img id="04" class="card" src="images/number 04.png" alt="4"></td>
                <td><img id="05" class="card" src="images/number 05.png" alt="5"></td>
                <td><img id="06" class="card" src="images/number 06.png" alt="6"></td>
                <td><img id="07" class="card" src="images/number 07.png" alt="7"></td>
                <td><img id="08" class="card" src="images/number 08.png" alt="8"></td>
                <td><img id="09" class="card" src="images/number 09.png" alt="9"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script src="../jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#orders").append("Click 5 number you like");
    var choose = 0;
    $(".card").click(function() {
        var $id = $(this).attr("id");
        $(this).attr("src", "images/choose"+$id+".png"); //i want to change the img if clicked
        ++choose;
    });
    
    if (choose == 5) {
        $("#orders p").remove();
        var display = "pfftt";
        $("#orders").append(display);
    }
});
```

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: What does not work, you cant change images?

Comment: (General note: _“here if you want to download …”_ - no, we don’t; questions always need to contain a proper [mre] within themselves.)

Comment: `if (choose == 5)` is never going to be true here - at this point, the variable still has the value `0` that you initialized it with. You need to perform this check _inside_ your click handler, because that is where the variable gets _changed_.

Comment: That only a simple logic you have to create. Make sure you learn how to loop over html elements (DOM) in jQuery. You can use simple for loop or jQuery each.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen no, i  cant change the html content, the p element in the div with orders id

Comment: @CBroe omg thank you, it works. thank you so much. i alerted it outside the click handler unfortunately. im sorry

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#orders").append("Click 5 number you like");
    var choose = 0;
    $(".card").click(function() {
        var $id = $(this).attr("id");
        $(this).attr("src", "images/choose"+$id+".png");
        ++choose;

        if (choose == 5) {
             $("#orders p").remove();
             var display = "pfftt";
             $("#orders").append(display);
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: While this may solve the OP's problem, please consider always leaving a comment/explanation about what you have done and why this solves the problem.